# How to print data from api that has 50 call limit

Tags: python, mongodb, python-requests

I am trying to get data from an API that has a limit of 50 calls so i am looping with 400 iterations to collect all the data (around 2000).

For some reason, I keep getting printer 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.. 399. I want the data i'm getting from the API, not consecutive numbers! Any ideas?

```
from helpers import parse_meebit_data, parse_sale_data
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


# Making connection to MongoClient
client = 'my url'

#Creating database
db = client['meebitsDB']

# Creating collection/table
meebits_collection = db['meebitsCollection']
sales_collection = db['salesCollection']

# The source code below collects assets data 
# 'The API has a limit of 50 items per call, 

url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets"

for i in range(0, 400):
    param = {"token_ids":list(range((i*50)+1, (i*50)+51)),
                   "asset_contract_address":"0x7Bd29408f11D2bFC23c34f18275bBf23bB716Bc7",
                   "order_direction":"desc",
                   "offset":"0",
                   "limit":"50"}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, params=param)

    print(response.text)
```

If i include the following code then my output becomes `0 connection error`

```
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Connection error')
        break
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are never printing anything from the response. Only your index variable `i`

Comment: ok that makes sense.. when i try print(response.json) i get a new error so i think im in the right direction.. thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @LukeNelson Hi again, If have changed the print to print(response.text) which returns in terminal many lines of ` "detail": "Request was throttled." ` Would this be due to the rate limited OpenSea API im using? Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not really a "solution" to rate limits. However it is possible to try to optimize your code to limit how many api calls you make. For example, you could try to download as much data as you can at once, and cache it locally. This would mean your data is not always perfectly up to date, but that may be acceptable in your use case.